# How to make Ndepend console update FrameworkAssemblies automatically?

Tags: c#, ndepend

When loading an assembly in Ndepend, it's dependencies (called FrameworkAssemblies  in the xml project file) are automatically found and displayed.

But when using Ndepend in console mode, the FrameworkAssemblies are not updated automatically, they are only read.

Does NDepend already provide any mean to do that automatically? or should we write ourselves a script?
The goal is to avoid maintaining dependencies 3 times: in csproj, in Ndepend project file, in maven pom files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your NDepend project on the fly through NDepend.API as shown in this [NDepend.API Getting Started page](http://www.ndepend.com/API/NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html). In such case the third-party assemblies are resolved on the current machine at the NDepend project creation time.